# winsock program

Tags: vb.net, winsock

hai sir how to communicate remote system using win sock control through internet. this is possiple give example or any idea in vb.net 2005

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET has something better than Winsock -- it has a set of simple and useful networking functions.

If you really need 'socket', try the [MSDN System.Net.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx) documentation

Many people who use sockets really need to connect to an HTTP server; for that use the [System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.aspx) documentation and look for the Http classes -- start with WebRequest

[Note: I work at Microsoft]